Looking for an argument why $e^{-tK}$ is completely positive for $K(A):=\frac{1}{2}(VA+AV^*)$
A completely positive map $\Phi : M_d(\mathbb{C})\longrightarrow M_d(\mathbb{C})$ is a map such that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the map
$$\Phi  \otimes Id_n : M_d(\mathbb{C})\otimes M_n(\mathbb{C}) \longrightarrow M_d(\mathbb{C}) \otimes M_n(\mathbb{C})$$
is positive (mapping positive elements onto positive elements).
Let now $\Phi$ be such a completely positive map and $H=H^*$ self adjoint matrix in $M_d(\mathbb{C})$. Additionaly define $V:=\Phi(Id_d)-2iH$ and
$$K(A):=\frac{1}{2}(VA+AV^*).$$
In the Book Quantum dynamical systems (Alicki and Fannes) Page 161. The authors argue, that $e^{-tK}$ is a completely positive map (for any $t\in \mathbb{R}^+$). Since sums, limits and products of completely positive maps are again c.p., this should boil down to the question why $-K(A)$ is completely positive.
Here I am stuck. I know that a map is c.p iff it can be written as $-K(A)=\sum_i W^*_i AW_i$ but if this is the criterion I dont see how it might be applied.

The claim that $K(A)$ should be completely positive seems to be false. In particular, if $\Phi$ is unital and we take $H = 0$, then we end up with $-K(A) = -A$, which clearly fails to be positive.

Some potentially helpful observations, for whatever it is that you're ultimately trying to prove here: for positive $A,B,$
$$
(K \otimes \text{Id}_n)(A \otimes B) = \frac 12 (VA) \otimes B + \frac 12(AV^) \otimes B \
= \frac 12 (V \otimes I_n) (A \otimes B) + \frac 12 (A \otimes B)(V \otimes I_n)^
$$
Also, $(M - 2iH) \otimes I_n = M \otimes I_n - 2i(H \otimes I_n)$ Thus, proving that $K$ is positive is sufficient to conclude that it is completely positive.

I was a bit surprised by the following result, but I imagine that the authors have established the following somewhere earlier in the text.

Claim: For $U \in M_d$, Let $K_U: M_d \to M_d$ denote the map $K_U(A) = UA + AU^*$. Then $\exp(K_U)(A) = \exp(U)A \exp(U)^*$. It follows that $\exp(K_U)$ is a completely positive map.

All that remains is to substitute $U = -\frac 12 tV$.

Proof of claim: With (column-major) vectorization, we note that
$$
\operatorname{vec}(K_U(A)) = \operatorname{vec}(UA) + \operatorname{vec}(AU^*)\\
= (I_d \otimes U)\operatorname{vec}(A) + (\overline{U} \otimes I_d)\operatorname{vec}(A)\\
= [I_d \otimes U + \overline{U} \otimes I_d]\operatorname{vec}(A)\\
= [\overline U \oplus U]\operatorname{vec}(A),
$$
where $\oplus$ denotes the Kronecker sum (cf. property 8 from the list of properties linked). It follows that
$$
\operatorname{vec}(\exp(K_U)(A))
= \exp(\overline U \oplus U) \operatorname{vec}(A)
\\ = [\exp(\overline U) \otimes \exp(U)] \operatorname{vec}(A)
\\ = \operatorname{vec}(\exp(U) A \exp(U^*)).
$$
The conclusion follows. $\square$
As an alternative approach, one might note that the maps $L_U:A \mapsto UA$ and $R_U:A \mapsto AU^*$ commute. From there, it is relatively straightforward to show that $\exp(L_U)(A) = \exp(U)A$ and $\exp(R_U)(A) = A\exp(U^*) = A\exp(U)^*$. From there, it suffices to note that $\exp(L_U + R_U) = \exp(L_U) \circ \exp(R_U)$.

A neat consequence of the above observation claim: for any Hermitian $H$, the positive operators
$$
\phi_t(A) = \exp(itH)A\exp(itH)^*
$$
form a semigroup. The generator of this semigroup is apparently the operator $K_{H}$.

Hey, thanks. I already showed some other way that the exponential of such form is always positive. (it maps selfadjoint to selfadjoint matrices, so we can diagonalize the exponential for positive input and get a positive operator after taking the exponential of the diagonal matrix (only positive entrees). But I failed to conclude that the map is also completely positive. (The fuzz is about the Lindblad Formular in the book)

@CoffeeArabica Well, with my proof you can see that it's completely positive since we have a Kraus decomposition (with one term in the sum)

@CoffeeArabica And to be honest I have no idea what you're getting at with the summary you gave of your proof. It sounds like you're taking the exponential of the positive definite matrices that the map acts upon rather than taking the exponential of the map itself

@CoffeeArabica Or maybe you meant that you could use the diagonalization of $V$ to diagonalize $K$ and thus $e^K$. If that's the case, then sure that makes sense; you just need to be aware that not every $V$ of the form described will be diagonalizable which means that you might need to make an argument via limits.
